# Character's face gets 'wrinkly' when its blendshapes (shape keys) are animated in Unity

Tags: export, import

Image: [image]

So I'm trying to use a head FBX provided by Unity. It's this head here: [https://github.com/needle-mirror/com.unity.live-capture/blob/master/Samples~/ARKit%20Face%20Sample/SampleHead.fbx](https://github.com/needle-mirror/com.unity.live-capture/blob/master/Samples%7E/ARKit%20Face%20Sample/SampleHead.fbx)

It comes with 52 blendshapes (shape keys) for face animation.

If I just upload this FBX straight into Unity and animate the blendshapes, it looks good.

**However**, if I upload this FBX into Blender, and then export the FBX again (Armature+Mesh only), and *then* import it back into Unity... then the face gets all wrinkly when animated like shown in the provided screenshot.

Why do I need to be able to run it through Blender? because I want to make edits to the model and then import it back into Unity. But if I can't even import it and export it from Blender (with NO model changes... only doing a test import/export) without it getting wrinkly, then I feel I'm running into a brick wall here.

Any ideas what might be the cause of these weird 'wrinkles' after a Blender import+export? Thanks!

Comment: I still don't get why you need to export from Unity to Blender and then to Unity again. The normal workflow is simply to make edits on Blender and export updates to Unity. Making back and forth exports is literally multiplying the changes of having issues.

Comment: Oh, I don't export from Unity. I just mean that I downloaded the file from GitHub and then imported it into Blender and exported it from Blender. *Then* import into Unity. When it goes through Blender like that, even when I make no changes to the model, Unity shows these 'wrinkles' when animating. On the other hand if I never run it through Blender and just import the FBX from GitHub directly into Unity, then Unity does not show wrinkles. So I think there is something about it going through Blender that causes a problem

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. Perhaps the normals have been somehow baked in place with the default face, and so it goes all wrong as soon as you change the shape. This could be delt with either during the export or the import, and even in the asset's settings in Unity. I don't have Unity right now, but try playing with Blender's FBX exporter Smoothing options. Also make sure you only select what you need to export and use [these settings](https://i.imgur.com/KfJhAQL.jpeg). It's from faint memories, but I think that's the ones we need for Unity.